# Django class-based-view access context data from get_queryset

Tags: python, django

```
class ProfileContextMixin(generic_base.ContextMixin, generic_view.View):

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(ProfileContextMixin, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        profile = get_object_or_404(Profile, user__username=self.request.user)
        context['profile'] = profile
        return context

class CourseListView(ProfileContextMixin, generic_view.ListView):
    model = Course
    template_name = 'course_list.html'
    object_list = None

    def get_queryset(self):
        profile = self.get_context_data()['profile']
        return super(CourseListView, self).get_queryset().filter(creator=profile)
```

I have the following two class-based-views. `CourseListView` inherits `ProfileContextMixin` which I wrote so that I don't have to repeat overriding `get_context_data` to get the `profile` every time in my other views.

Now in my `CourseListView`, I need to filter the result based on the `creator` argument, which is the same one retrieved in `get_context_data`

I know my `get_queryset` works, and it will call `get_context_data()` to get the profile, but this will also cause my `get_context_data` to be called twice, executing the same SQL two times.

Is there a way I can access the context efficiently?

**UPDATE:**

After reading `ListView` method flowchart, I ended up doing this, but not sure if it's the best way. Feedback is appreciated.

```
    object_list = []
    context = None

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        return self.context

    def get_queryset(self):
        self.context = super(CourseListView, self).get_context_data()
        profile = self.context['profile']
        queryset = super(CourseListView, self).get_queryset()
        queryset = queryset.filter(creator=profile)
        self.context['object_list'] = queryset
        return queryset
```

Answer (score 2):

You can move getting profile out of `get_context_data` to upper function, like `dispatch`, or use [`cached_property`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/ref/utils/#django.utils.functional.cached_property) decorator. This way your profile will be stored in `_profile` argument of view and you will not do second `get` to DB after calling `self.profile` second time.

```
from django.utils.functional import cached_property

class ProfileContextMixin(generic_base.ContextMixin, generic_view.View):
    @cached_property
    def profile(self):
        return get_object_or_404(Profile, user__username=self.request.user)

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(ProfileContextMixin, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        context['profile'] = self.profile
        return context

class CourseListView(ProfileContextMixin, generic_view.ListView):
    model = Course
    template_name = 'course_list.html'
    object_list = None

    def get_queryset(self):
        return super(CourseListView, self).get_queryset().filter(creator=self.profile)
```

Comment: Thanks! I've been reading about `cached_property` and I haven't seen it used in views. Is it safe to put it in a view? How do you invalidate the cached property if you wanted to?

Comment: It is safe. It is stored on class instance. So it will exists only from the moment when you do request on view, till this view returns response, because views are instantiated each time you do request. It is almost same as doing assigning in `__init__` so your `self.argument` can be called in any other method. But in Django you can't just do it in  `__init__` so they came up with this method.